# I get a blank when I try to retrieve the values set for the object $obj

Tags: php, class

In the following script I try to set the values for `$var_1` and `$var_2` using the `set` method for the object `$obj`. But when I call the get method to retrieve the values set for that object,I get a blank. Why is that ?

```
<?php
class Tester {

    public $var_1;
    public $var_2;

    public function set() {
        $var_1 = 20;
        $var_2 = "Tu jo aa jaaye..toh is ghar ko sawanrta dekhun";
    }

    public function get() {
        return "Var_1 is : {$var_1} and Var_2 is : {$var_2}";
    }
}

$obj = new Tester();
$obj_c = clone $obj;
$obj_nc = $obj;

$obj->set();
echo $obj->get();

echo $obj_nc->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$this` is required in PHP. You're referencing local variables otherwise.

```
public function someFunc()
{
    //$this->var and $var are in no way linked:
    $var = 1; //A local variable named $var with a value of 1
    $this->var = 2; // A property of $this object with a value of 2
}
```

---

As a side note, you should develop with `display_errors` `On` and [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) cranked all the way up. If that had been the case, you would have seen notices that you were references undefined variables. (Note that error_reporting arguably should be cranked all the way up on production servers [if your code was coded with it mind], but `display_errors` should never be `On` in a production environment -- logs should be used instead.)